# Автоматический скрол в низ страницы

Tags: jquery, css-animation

https://antoni.de/culture/ -пример

Всем доброго времени суток. Подскажите не опытному, как проделать данную операцию?
У меня уже сайт готов и настроен. Нужна только такая анимация. Не могу понять как ее сделать.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/52jzM/1/  так устроит ?

Comment: http://aksis.at/home/ - мне подходит, все очень круто, мне так и надо. Но я не могу разместить данный код на сайте моем. возможно Вы мне поможите?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yjYJ4/ - вот так лучше, только изменить скорость на 55000

Comment: на какой cms ваш сайт ?

Comment: wordpress у меня. Нужно чтобы это было только на одной странице. А не на всех

Comment: я с wp не работаю - к сожалению ,обратитесь на фриланс  или спросите тут же ...скрипт же есть

Comment: я нашел решение, но проблема в селудующем. скрол не работает. нужно чтобы автоматически листал (как сейчас) но и чтобы можно было самому тоже листать вгору-вниз

Comment: в вашем примере так и работает  - проверил только что

Comment: вообще в wp нету страниц, там только ключевые страницы а вся информация из db и как подключить только к одно понятия не имею, я наверно единственный враг wordpress

Comment: после того как подключил скрипт...мне не дает возможности листать страницу самому

Comment: вообще на wordpress можно подключить отдельную статичную страницу но она не будет редактироваться из панели администратора но будет находится в составе wp

Comment: Мне кажится что нужно изменить немного код, у меня не хватает опыта чтобы это сделать. Чтобы самому тоже можно было скролить страницу, помимо автоматической анимации

Comment: я вам скинул готовый код , там вс само делается + можно и самому скролить ...остальное на фриланс или просите помощи [ТУТ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, за предоставленное время

Answer (score -2):

Как по мне, тут по дефолту стоит active на нижнем блоке и якорем оно его опускает, просто медленно. (Могу ошибаться)

Comment: Возможно и так. Но как реализовать кодом?

Comment: Делаешь анимацию, то есть -*overmuch px вниз и делаешь плавную анимацию на верх(по времени долго). Кодом, к сожалению, не помогу.